# Can I compose an InvokeDynamic with a FixedValue using Implementation.Composable#andThen()?

Tags: byte-buddy

I am building a method "by hand" in ByteBuddy.  The method I'm building has one parameter of type `ProductType`.  Let's say it looks like this:

```
public ProductType frob(ProductType product) {
  // stuff that I'm implementing and asking about goes here
}
```

Inside that method I am building the equivalent of:

```
product.foo(); // more on this below; foo() has a void return type, which may be important
return product; // FixedValue.argument(0)
```

This works fine when I build an `Implementation` like this:

```
MethodCall.invoke(fooMethodDescription) // invoke foo()...
  .onArgument(0) // ...on product...
  .andThen(FixedValue.argument(0)); // ...and then return product
```

(I hope I've typed that right.)

If, however, I build an `Implementation` like this:

```
InvokeDynamic.bootstrap(...) // look up foo()'s MethodHandle via my bootstrap method...
  .invoke("foo", TypeDescription.VOID) // ...invoke the method handle with a return type of void...
  .withArgument(0) // ..."on" the first and only argument (product) and "with" no other arguments...
  .andThen(FixedValue.argument(0)); // ...and then return product
```

…with, of course, the proper `InvokeDynamic` recipe, the resulting class cannot be verified because of an `Operand stack underflow` error (`Attempt to pop empty stack`).

I have a similar `InvokeDynamic` recipe used many places elsewhere so I know that my problem is not with the `InvokeDynamic` usage.  Rather, it seems to be with the composing? maybe?  Is it possible that `MethodCall` and `InvokeDynamic` behave differently, even though both are `Implementation`s?  Maybe `InvokeDynamic` doesn't push something on the operand stack (maybe just in the case of `void` returns?) whereas `MethodCall` does?  Is there something I'm missing in the `andThen()` usage?

Using ByteBuddy 1.11.2.

Comment: I'm beginning to think this may be a bug in the handling of `void` return types and `InvokeDynamic`. Specifically, I'm not sure a `void` return type is ever stacked, so the `TerminationHandler.DROPPING` tries to `pop` something that isn't there. What I don't know is if _I_ am supposed to know this and do something about it. I've tried a few things with `Implementation.Compound` to try to artificially stack a return value so it will get popped, but that leads to other errors and I don't really know what I'm doing. :-)

Comment: Changing `TerminationHandler.DROPPING` such that `returnType` is the value passed to `Removal.of()` fixes this problem, but I don't know what other repercussions this might have.  Filing an issue.

Comment: Filed https://github.com/raphw/byte-buddy/issues/1069.

Comment: PR: https://github.com/raphw/byte-buddy/pull/1070

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you pointed out correctly, this is a bug in Byte Buddy that is now fixed. Thanks for that. It will be released with version *1.11.3*.